# typescript understanding the type definitation

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and trying to understand this following code
Can someone please help and if there is any good course/book to learn typescript

```
type ConfigFactoryReturnValue =
  | Record<string, any>
  | Promise<Record<string, any>>;

export type ConfigFactory<
  T extends ConfigFactoryReturnValue = ConfigFactoryReturnValue
> = () => T;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block combined between `type alias` and `union type`, that means you defined your own data type name `ConfigFactoryReturnValue` and that data type can be `Record<string, any>` or `Promise<Record<string, any>>`

```
type ConfigFactoryReturnValue =
  | Record<string, any>
  | Promise<Record<string, any>>;
```

The second block combining `type alias` with `generics` feature of typescript.
That means exporting `alias type` of a generic type.

`<T extends ConfigFactoryReturnValue = ConfigFactoryReturnValue>` define that the type `T` should extend from `ConfigFactoryReturnValue` or is instance of `ConfigFactoryReturnValue` as default.

```
export type ConfigFactory<
  T extends ConfigFactoryReturnValue = ConfigFactoryReturnValue
> = () => T;
```

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is a bit open-ended and broad still, I'll try to provide some information about the code you've shared.

```
// The type keyword is used to define a type, for example
type MyCustomType = string;

// Record<K, T> is a Utility type for handling objects.
// Record defines the type of key:value pair.

// This means that MyRecord is an object whose keys are string and can have any value
type MyRecord = Record<string, any>;

// Promise is used to determine a Promise type, which means a method which returns a Promise
// Promise<T> is the syntax in which T determines the type of returned value when promise is resolved

// ConfigFactoryReturnValue is a Type which can be an object of type string:any or promise<Object<string, any>>
type ConfigFactoryReturnValue = Record<string, any> | Promise<Record<string, any>>;

// The Type T extends ConfigFactoryReturnValue signifies that Generic type T must satisfy the type
// ConfigFactoryReturnValue i.e. along with other keys it should have keys defined in ConfigFactoryReturnValue
export type ConfigFactory<T extends ConfigFactoryReturnValue> = () => T;
```

as far as the Typescript course/book is concerned, there are plenty of courses available online on platforms like Udemy, Coursera, etc.